# How to load assets before Rails response

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a huge amount data in DB for my Rails app and loading pages(where are huge and slow SQL requests) takes a lot of time. I need to display HTML and CSS first and show loading icon to user while SQL request performs. So how could I display CSS before Rails response ?

Comment: Load an empty page from your app and have some javascript on that empty page that loads the actual data in a second request.

Comment: Have you tried to improve the responsiveness of your app before going to such drastic measures (caching, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries are executed on server side,and based on these queries result rails generate views and then send back these views to requesting user browser. This is the default behavior of request-response cycle.

You can achieve your goal by displaying simple page with only loading image/css in response to request and then load data using ajax.